# FTP Command Line - "Connection closed by remote host"

Tags: ms-access, ftp

I have an Access DB app that exports a table (to XLS) then FTPs to our FTP server over our VPN.  This routine has been working for several years, until ~yesterday.  I am not sure what could have changed to break this function.

This is not really an Access DB issue as I see the same "Closed Connection" when manually attempting to FTP PUT at the Windows command line.  Other users of the Access app (VPN and local) are not seeing this same issue.

I did receive a Win10 Security update this week - possible this affected my firewall settings?

Any suggestions where to begin?  Googling suggests to portforward Port 20/21, but this seems to have no effect either.

Thank You!

Note 1:  I do use WinSCP for passive transfers for another specific task to FTP to a 3rd party who requires passive transfers.  Some of our users in India are unable to use this tool reliably, so I am hesitant to convert this basic function in my Access app as it works everywhere but my local machine.

Note 2: I attempted to add "QUOTE PASV" before a command line transfer with no effect.  As I am reading, Windows FTP utility does not support Passive transfers

Note 3:  FileZilla can see and transfer to the FTP server using "Plain FTP" mode.  Interesting, but I really need this to work via command line without requiring a 3rd part app installation.

Note 4:  I uninstalled the Win10 Security Update - No effect

Comment: You have to show us complete `ftp.exe` output and your script, otherwise we can hardly help you. Though as Windows `ftp.exe` does not support passive mode, it's actually surprising that it ever worked for you. + *"Some of our users in India are unable to use this tool [WinSCP] reliably"* - What specific problem do they have? + *"suggests to portforward Port 20/21, but this seems to have no effect either."* - What exactly did you do to *"portforward Port 20/21"*?

Comment: @Martin - thanks and sorry for the weak question.  Keeping this simple, I cannot use FTP from Win10 command line.  I CAN FTP with my laptop directly connected (Cat 5) to my cable modem.  New Google WiFi router is suspect, but no clue where to begin to diagnose.

Comment: Start by answering my questions (edit your question).

Comment: @AnthonyHorne The OP is using command-line `ftp`, that's what the question is about. And command-line `ftp` does not support TLS/SSL anyway, so tighter TLS/SSL cannot be an issue here.